# In Metal Gear Solid 5 Phantom Pain, why does Snake pretend to shoot the children?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

In the part where Snake finds the kids in a cell offering diamonds in exchange for their freedom, snake shoots at a bucket and Kaz says "it's on recording", what was the purpose of that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

He does this to trick the contractor.

Snake and his group are mercenaries. He was hired to take out the former Mbele soldiers. The contractor failed to mention that some of them are children.

Snake isn't really the guy who kills children, but he needs the money, so he decided to deceive the contractor by recording the fake execution.

Comment: To add to this, you can hear Miller say over the radio "Tape's rolling, Boss" before he opens fire, and he then confirms immediately afterwards that it was all caught on tape.